# Why 'var ehy = "php echo $dunno"'?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, explode

I want to get some keyword by a textarea by using this js code. Obviously, I need PHP code too, but I have a problem with the string - `var ehy = "php echo $dunno"`. Why this? Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['line'])) {
$line = $_POST['line'];
$dunno = (explode(" ", $line));
}
?>
<script>
function countLines(){
    var stringLength = document.getElementById("myText").value.length;
    var count = Math.ceil( stringLength / document.getElementById("myText").cols ); 
    // just devide the absolute string length by the amount of horizontal place and ceil it
    return count;
    }
function what(){
    var n = countLines()
    var tarea = document.getElementById('myText')
    var lines = tarea.value.split("\n")
    //for(var x = 0; x < lines.length; x++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: "line="+lines,
            success: function(){
                var ehy = "<?php echo $dunno; ?>"
                $('#what').text(ehy)
                },
            });
        //} 
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>SearchFunction()</h1>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="70" id="myText"><?php echo "what the hell?";?></textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="what()"/>
    <p id="try"></p>
    <p id="what"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$dunno` seems to be an array so using `"<?php echo $dunno; ?>"` is not correct. As a general rule of thumb: always use `json_encode` to export PHP values to JavaScript.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: you should post that as an answer; you've hit the nail on the head. (Even if it's just a plain string, he should use `json_encode()`, to ensure it's escaped properly).

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is some HTML-like page with little bits of PHP in it.

```
<html>
<?php echo 'hi' ?>
</html>
```

On your server, the php gets processed and all the  tags get replaced:

```
<html>
hi
</html>
```

In your particular situation, the place where you echo `$dunno` is in the middle of some embedded javascript.

All of this happens on the server. The client (browser) did nothing so far.

Now that the page is ready, it gets to the browser which interprets it. The browser doesn't get the  bits because they have already been interpreted. The browser simply gets a HTML with some JS:

```
var ehy = 5
```

At an even later point, when the `what` function is executed, it will trigger an ajax request that on success sets the text of `#what` to the value determined a long time ago by the PHP interpreter.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why this? doesn't if(isset($_POST['line'])) resolve the matter? when page load, this php code is not executed, isn't it?

Comment: Chrome console also get a syntax error (var ehy = <br/> Unexpected token <). What the hell this means?